# how do i add $_POST mutiple times in a single variable in php

Tags: php, variables, global

I am using mail function to receive email from customer and display the submitted data directly to my email.
How to add multiple global variable `$_POST['']` in a single variable, since following code of mine does not work:

```
$message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " details are:" . "\n\n\n\n" . $_POST['father_name'],$_POST['dob'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['address'],$_POST['contact_number'];
```

Comment: Use concatenation operator(.) instead of comma. Read this link for more details. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: i had used these code in php:

$message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " details are:" . "\n\n\n\n" . "{$_POST['father_name']},{$_POST['dob']},{$_POST['email']},{$_POST['address']},{$_POST['contact_number']}";

my output is:- kunal kumar deatails are:-

Robert kumar,2016-05-11,vicky@gmail.com,delhi,9925151414

but i want output like this:

List item Name:Robert kumar
List item DOB:2016-05-11
List item email:vicky@gmail.com
List item Address:delhi
List item contact no:9925151414
plz help

Comment: @vicky Don't put code in comments, edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want add comma separator so Use this

```
$message = $first_name . " " .  $last_name . " details are:" . "\n\n\n\n" . "{$_POST['father_name']},{$_POST['dob']},{$_POST['email']},{$_POST['address']},{$_POST['contact_number']}";
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP syntax doesn't use commas (like perl), you'll need to use something like the following. And always filter your inputs!

```
$filtered = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, [
  "father_name"    => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
  "dob"            => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
  "email"          => FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL,
  "address"        => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
  "contact_number" => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
]);
$message  = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " details are:" . "\n\n\n\n";
$message .= $filtered['father_name'];
$message .= $filtered['dob'];
$message .= $filtered['email'] ?: "invalid email";
$message .= $filtered['address'];
$message .= $filtered['contact_number'];
```

If you would like newlines, append `. "\n"` to each concatenated field before the semicolon. If you would like html list-items (your follow-up comment seems unclear to me), wrap each concatenated field in `<li>` tags:

i.e.,

```
// ... (see above)
$message .= "<li>" . $filtered['father_name'] . "</li>";
// ... (same for other fields)
```

Answer (score 0):

try simple concatenation 
`$message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " details are:" . "\n\n\n\n" . $_POST['father_name'].','.$_POST['dob'].','.$_POST['email'].','.$_POST['address'].','.$_POST['contact_number'];`